# Javascript: Code is called on load but should run when a click event happened

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

I am trying to understand the Javascript event handling. I like some code to be called when I press a button and added an eventlistener - my code:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>
        PDSA #4.4: Event Registering
    </title>
    <script>
        function changeTheButton(btn){
            btn.innerHTML = "Please, don't press again!";
            alert("Changed the button");
        }

        function init(){
            btn = document.getElementById("button1");
            btn.addEventListener("click", changeTheButton(btn), false);
        }
    </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="init()">
    <form>
        <button id="button1">Don't press this button</button>
    </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I open this site in Chrome or Firefox the text on the button is already "Please, don't press again!" and the alert is opened before I do anything.

Why does this happen? I expected this to happen, when I press the button and not on load.

Thanks in advance for any help
André

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch this line:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", changeTheButton(btn), false);
```

You're actually calling `changeTheButton` right there, resulting in the `alert`. You probably want to register it as an event handler instead, thus deferring the alert until the button is pressed:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function() { changeTheButton(btn) }, false);
```

You can watch the result at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A35qX/).

One additional problem you might experience is that the button click causes a page reload, because the default event handler is still called. You can prevent that by calling `.preventDefault()` on the event instance:

```
function changeTheButton(ev, btn) {
    alert("Changed the button");
    btn.innerHTML = "Please, don't press again!";
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function init(){
    btn = document.getElementById("button1");
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(ev) { 
        changeTheButton(ev, btn) 
    }, false);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A35qX/4/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer. Can you tell me why the button text changes back to "Don't press this button" when i click on "OK" on the alert? I would like the button text to stay as "Please, don't press again!" when it was clicked.

Comment: @Andre: Well, you just need to switch the operations inside `changeTheButton` :) If you want to `alert` first, just `alert` first ;)

Comment: Even if I first execute the alert the text on the button still changes back to "Don't press this button" after the click event. But I would like it to stay "Please, don't press again!". Any ideas?

Comment: Deleted one comment as there was just an update problem in jsfiddle. Also works for me but the text still changes back.

Comment: @Andre: Yes, that's because the default action on a button click is to submit a form, thus reloading the page in this case. What you could do is to call `.preventDefault()` on the event instance. I'll add an example.

Comment: Okay, now I get it!! Forgot about the submit. Thanks a lot!